# Microsoft Excel - Merging and consolidating issue

Tags: excel, merge

I Have three columns in excel:

```
 Column A: Category
 Column B: Value
 Column C: Value
```

I want to consolidate the list such that if I have rows like below:

```
A1:Car     | B1:Ford   | C1:Toyota
A2:Scooter | B2:Honda  | C2:(blank)
A3:Bike    | B3:Yamaha | C3:Ducati
```

Gives me a result:

```
A1:Car     | B1:Ford
A2:Car     | B2:Toyota
A3:Scooter | B3:Honda
A4:Bike    | B4:Yamaha
A5:Bike    | B5:Ducati
```

[Image explaining the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv7M5.png)

Comment: Macro suggested by Marco worked! Many thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would do the trick, asuming that this is all happening on the activesheet.

```
Sub consolidate()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastCol As Integer 
Dim counterRow As Integer
Dim counterCol As Integer 
Dim counterDestinationRow As Integer
Dim destination As Object

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set destination = Cells(lastRow + 2, 1)
'or to another sheet: Set destination = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)

For counterRow = 1 To lastRow

  lastCol = Cells(counterRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For counterCol = 2 To lastCol

        destination.Offset(counterDestinationRow, 0) = Cells(counterRow, 1)
        destination.Offset(counterDestinationRow, 1) = Cells(counterRow, counterCol)

        counterDestinationRow = counterDestinationRow + 1

    Next counterCol

Next counterRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Marco. It worked partially. Is there a email address where I can share the actual spreadsheet with you?

Comment: Sure, Use marcotemp@yopmail.com

Answer (score 0):

No programming, just copy paste.

Step 0: SAVE AS NEW SHEET :)

1. insert a column before C (this is the new column C)
2. Copy values from Column A category to Column C (copy as text)
3. select all values in columns C and D, copy an paste directly under last values A and B.
4. remove columns c and d
5. Sort on column A then B, remove empty rows with empty value columns

Comment: Thanks Sascha. 

Thanks Jan. 
The issue is that it is not a one time thing. 
It's a monthly report.
Using a index vlookup formula I have gotten values like 'Ford' and 'Toyota' against 'Car' category from input file. 
Now i need to bring output into the required format (in a separate sheet) using formulae so that the output file can feed into the pivot and graphs

Comment: Is there anything to gain from the source? Where does the data come from?

Comment: Hi Jan. thanks. The source is coming from a periodic report and contains quite a few columns. I need to lookup in an existing matrix and find a corresponding value for the concatenation of the input columns. The problem is lookup results are multiple, so I bring them over using index formula (like ford and Toyota in my problem statement)